# Reference same template in two different places for rendering inside a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have this component:

```html
<template>

  <div>    

    <!-- If usecard is true, I want to render a wrapper -->
    <v-card flat v-if="usecard">
      <v-container>

        <!-- I want to reference the errors template here -->

      </v-container>
    </v-card>

    <!-- If usecard is false, I want to render only the errors template -->
    <div v-if="!usecard">

      <!-- I want to reference the errors template here -->

    </div>

    <!-- Template for error stuff -->
    <template id="errors">
      <v-layout row wrap v-if="errors.length">
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-alert :value="true" type="error">
            <ul>
              <li v-for="(error, i) in errors" :key="i + error">{{ error }}</li>
            </ul>
          </v-alert>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </template>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NuErrorList",
  props: {
    errors: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
    usecard: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: () => false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

Basically, I want to render a wrapper around a defined chunk of HTML without having to repeat it. I thought on defining a `template` and then referencing it in two different places that render alternatively depending on the value of the `usecard` prop. But I don't know how to reference that template from those two different places.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't slot work? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: @alt146 I don't think it's what I'm looking for here. I don't want a configurable slot here, just reuse the same template inside the component.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component that you want to show in multiple pages.
Then the component render it in `App.vue` and inside the component element add

```
        <router-view></router-view>
```

With this way you use one code base and you show it to the other pages
**App.vue**

```
   <v-app>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
       <myTemplateComponentVisibleToAllpages>
         <router-view></router-view>
       </myTemplateComponentVisibleToAllpages>
      </div>
     </v-app>
```

Comment: The question isn't about that.